# Jest + Enzyme testing if an element was focused to

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test if an element is focused to when the component updated.

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.button.focus();
  }
```

I have a render function which gets the component(s)

```
  function render(args) {
    const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...args} />);

    return {
      component,
      button: () => component.find("button"),
    };
  }
```

My assertion is as follows

```
describe("When component did update", () => {
  it("Should focus to the button", () => {
    const { component, button } = render(args);
    expect(button().focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

With just this I get the error

> Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

So I thought I needed to add a mock of `focus` which I've now done in my `beforeEach`, and test that instead, which removes the error but my test asserts `0 calls` instead of `1 call`:

```
describe("When component did update", () => {
  it("Should focus to the button", () => {
    const { component, button } = render(defaultArgs);
    expect(backButtonElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

So I must be missing something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your test asserts `0 calls` instead of the expected `1 call` is because `componentDidUpdate` does not trigger when the component mounts, only on subsequent updates. You need to trigger an update.

```js
describe("When component did update", () => {
  it("Should focus to the button", () => {
    const { component, button } = render(defaultArgs);
    /* 
       setting some random props to force an update,
       ideally you should simulate a real update/user behaviour 
       when you want the focus triggered
    */
    component.setProps({ forceUpdate: true });
    component.update();

    expect(backButtonElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

---

However, in order to avoid testing internal implementation details, I would suggest to assert the expected *side-effects* that the user should perceive. So, rather than checking if a function was called or not, checking that the button **is** focused when certain conditions occur:

```js
describe("When component did update", () => {
  it("Should focus to the button", () => {
    const { component, button } = render(defaultArgs);

    // trigger an update, ideally via user interaction
    // e.g.
    // component.simulate('click')

    // check which element is focused in the document
    const focusedElement = document.activeElement;

    expect(button().node.matchesElement(focusedElement)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```js
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

const input = wrapper.find('input');

expect(input).toHaveFocus();
```